# Disable fields of a chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, fusioncharts

(Image at the bottom of the page)

I have this table, it is about light patterns and it is represented from 1 to 8, what I do is that by means of Charts function I fill the table with the fields that you see on the left (Cambio, Hora/%, Minutos, Dimado y Dimado entrada)
The graph at this moment works well, if I modify the values ​​on the left the table is modified. Now, what I try is that, not always the 8 fields will be active so I want to disappear from view the fields that are not active. for example: The select "1" of "cambio" is active, then it will be seen in the graph, but if the select "2" of " is inactive it will not be seen in the graph
Any ideas what to do?

The code of the table is this:

```
    <table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Patrón 2</strong>(
        <select name="TipoPatron2" id="TipoPatron2">
          <option value="00">T desde el encendido</option>
          <option value="01" selected="selected">T desde las 12:00</option>
          <option value="10">T en % respecto día anterior</option>
        </select>)</td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="changeP2();Campos2Mem()" value="Actualizar"> <label id="Error2" style="color: red"></label></td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr color="#ccff00">
              <td>Cambio</td>
              <td>Hora/%</td>
              <td>Minutos</td>
              <td>Dimado</td>
              <td>Dimado Entrada</td>
              <td>Color</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="mytbody2">
          </tbody>
        
            <script language="javascript">
                const tbody2 = document.getElementById("mytbody2");
                var I = 1;
                for (I = 1; I <= 8; I++) {
                    document.writeln("<tr align=center>");
                    document.writeln("<td>" + I + " <input type=\"checkbox\" checked id=\"AP2C" + I + "\"></td>");
                    document.writeln("<td><input type=\"text\" onpaste = \"alerta()\" value=\"0\" id=\"HP2C" + I + "\" maxlength=3 size=3></td>");
                    document.writeln("<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" id=\"MP2C" + I + "\" maxlength=2 size=2></td>");
                    document.writeln("<td><select name=\"dimado\" id=\"DP2C" + I + "\"><option value =\"0\">0%</option><option value =\"1\">1%</option><option value =\"2\">2%</option><option value =\"3\">3%</option><option value =\"4\">4%</option><option value =\"5\">5%</option><option value =\"6\">6%</option><option value =\"7\">7%</option><option value =\"8\">8%</option><option value =\"9\">9%</option><option value=\"10\">10%</option><option value=\"11\">11%</option><option value=\"12\">12%</option><option value=\"13\">13%</option><option value=\"14\">14%</option><option value = \"15\">15%</option><option value=\"16\">16%</option><option value=\"17\">17%</option><option value=\"18\">18%</option><option value=\"19\">19%</option><option value = \"20\">20%</option><option value=\"21\">21%</option><option value=\"10\">10%</option><option value = \"22\">22%</option><option value = \"23\">23%</option><option value = \"24\">24%</option><option value = \"25\">25%</option><option value = \"26\">26%</option><option value = \"27\">27%</option><option value = \"28\">28%</option><option value = \"29\">29%</option><option value = \"30\">30%</option><option value = \"31\">100%</option></select></td>");
                    document.writeln("<td><select name=\"dimadoEntrada\" id=\"IP2C" + I + "\" ><option value =\"0\">0%</option><option value =\"1\">1%</option><option value =\"2\">2%</option><option value =\"3\">3%</option><option value =\"4\">4%</option><option value =\"5\">5%</option><option value =\"6\">6%</option><option value =\"7\">7%</option><option value =\"8\">8%</option><option value =\"9\">9%</option><option value=\"10\">10%</option><option value=\"11\">11%</option><option value=\"12\">12%</option><option value=\"13\">13%</option><option value=\"14\">14%</option><option value = \"15\">15%</option><option value=\"16\">16%</option><option value=\"17\">17%</option><option value=\"18\">18%</option><option value=\"19\">19%</option><option value = \"20\">20%</option><option value=\"21\">21%</option><option value=\"10\">10%</option><option value = \"22\">22%</option><option value = \"23\">23%</option><option value = \"24\">24%</option><option value = \"25\">25%</option><option value = \"26\">26%</option><option value = \"27\">27%</option><option value = \"28\">28%</option><option value = \"29\">29%</option><option value = \"30\">30%</option><option value = \"31\">100%</option></select></td>");
                    document.writeln("<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" id=\"CP2C" + I + "\" maxlength=2 size=2 disabled></td>");
                    document.writeln("</tr>");
                }

                const HP2Cs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=HP2C]")
                    document.getElementById("TipoPatron2").addEventListener("change", function () {
                        const dis = this.value === "10";
                        HP2Cs.forEach(hp2c => hp2c.disabled = dis)
                    })
                
                    const Hrs2 = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=HP2C]")
                        document.getElementById("TipoPatron2").addEventListener("change", function () {
                        const dis = this.value === "00"  ;
                            Hrs2.forEach((hp2c, I) => {
                                if (dis) {
                                    console.log("AXZC");
                                    var new_element = document.createElement('td');
                                    new_element.innerHTML = "<select name=\"Hrs2\" id=\"HP2C" + I + "\"><option value =\"0\">0</option><option value =\"1\">1</option><option value =\"2\">2</option><option value =\"3\">3</option><option value =\"4\">4</option><option value =\"5\">5</option><option value =\"6\">6</option><option value =\"7\">7</option><option value =\"8\">8</option><option value =\"9\">9</option><option value =\"10\">10</option><option value =\"11\">11</option><option value =\"12\">12</option><option value =\"13\">13</option><option value =\"14\">14</option><option value =\"15\">15</option><option value =\"16\">16</option><option value =\"17\">17</option><option value =\"18\">18</option><option value =\"19\">19</option><option value =\"20\">20</option><option value =\"21\">21</option><option value =\"22\">22</option><option value =\"23\">23</option>";
                                    hp2c.replaceWith(new_element)
                                    const HP2Cs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=HP2C]")
                                        document.getElementById("TipoPatron2").addEventListener("change", function () {
                                            const dis = this.value === "10";
                                            HP2Cs.forEach(hp2c => hp2c.disabled = dis)
                    })
                              
                            }
                        })
                    })



            </script><tr align="center">
                </tbody>                    
    </table>
    </body>
    </td>
```

The code that generates the chart is

```
var dailyChart2 = new FusionCharts({
            id: 'p2chart',
            type: 'MSStepLine',
            renderAt: 'chart-container2',
            width: '550',
            height: '300',
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: {
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Patrón lumínico 2",
        "subcaption": "Personalizable",
        "xaxisname": "Horario",
        "yaxisname": "Nivel Dimado",
        "showvalues": "0",
        "bgalpha": "45",
        "bgcolor": "A6CAF0",
        "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
        "outcnvbasefont": "Verdana",
        "outcnvbasefontsize": "12",
        "canvasborderthickness": "2",
        "canvasbordercolor": "73A8E1",
        "anchorradius": "5",
        "anchorsides": "15",
        "anchorbgcolor": "FFFFFF",
        "linethickness": "4",
        "anchorborderthickness": "2",
        "divlinealpha": "5",
        "divlinecolor": "14C56E",
        "canvasborderalpha": "40",
        "outcnvbasefontcolor": "43302E",
        "legendbordercolor": "93C995",
        "legendborderalpha": "80",
        "legendborderthickness": "2",
        "bordercolor": "93C995",
        "borderalpha": "50",
        "useforwardsteps": "0",
        "showBorder": "0"
    },
    "categories": [
        {
            "category": [
                {
                    "label": ""
                },
                {
                    "label": "1"
                },
                {
                    "label": "2"
                },
                {
                    "label": "3"
                },
                {
                    "label": "4"
                },
                {
                    "label": "5"
                },
                {
                    "label": "6"
                },
                {
                    "label": "7"
                },
                {
                    "label": "8"
                },
                {
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dataset": [
        {
            "seriesname": "Patrón",
            "anchorbordercolor": "D30000",
            "color": "D30000",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "31"
                },
                {
                    "value": "31"
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C1").value
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C2").value
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C3").value
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C4").value
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C5").value
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C6").value
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C7").value
                },
                {
                    "value": document.getElementById("DP2C8").value
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
    }).render();
```

What I was saying is that, for example, if box 2 is deactivated in "Cambio" then it is not represented in the graph and therefore neither are the following.
That only the boxes that are activated are shown in the graph.

Image:

[image]

In the image you can see that the active fields are from 1 to 3, the others are not active so they represent a value of 0 in the graph, what I try is that they are not seen in this if they are not selected, Any ideas? I am somewhat stressed with this

Answer (score 0):

To Hide the Vertical Lines -
The step line chart displays the vertical joins - vertical lines that run through the edges of the horizontal planes thereby joining them in different steps. However, you can also disjoin the horizontal segments by hiding the vertical lines from the chart.

To hide the vertical lines in your chart, set the drawVerticalJoins attribute to 0.

```
{
    "chart": {
        "drawVerticalJoins": "0"
    }
}
```

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/5dm09d7y/

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/step-line-chart